# Parameterized JSON key naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  my_json: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  }
}
```

How can I customize key name via parameterized like:

```
def jsonize(custom_key="id")
{
    my_json: {
      "#{custom_key}": 1,
      name: "John"
    }
  }
end
```

To be output with:

Scenario 1:

```
=> jsonize
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  my_json: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  }
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
=> jsonize("value")
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  my_json: {
    value: 1,
    name: "John"
  }
}
```

Comment: You code will work and its correct.

Comment: Is this typo? `"#{custome_key}": 1,` it should be as `"#{custom_key}": 1,`.

Comment: Hi @GokulM, thanks for pointing the typo. But it is not what I meant. When I run the method it throws an error `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
      "#{custome_key}": 1,` because it should not be constructed like that. The question is, can I do a parameterized key naming? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert it to `symbol` and use `hash_rocket` syntax you will get the expected result

```
def jsonize(custom_key = "id")
  {
    my_json: {
      custom_key.to_sym => 1,
      name: "John"
    }
  }
end

#=> jsonize('foo')
#=> {
#=>     :my_json => {
#=>          :foo => 1,
#=>         :name => "John"
#=>     }
#=> }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ":" to separate symbolic keys and values, use "=>" in your example:

```
def jsonize(custom_key="id")
{
    my_json: {
      "#{custom_key}" => 1,
      name: "John"
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is right but I have to chose the answer to accept. So I will just vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The hash-rocket syntax has been in Ruby since ancient times:

```
{ :foo => 1, "bar" => 2 }
```

Ruby 1.9 (I think) introduced a new colon shortcut syntax just for symbols (while keeping the hash-rocket general for any key type):

```
{ foo: 1, "bar" => 2 }
```

Ruby 2.2 (I think) introduced the possibility of symbolizing a string in this syntax:

```
{ "foo": 1, "bar" => 2 }
```

All of these do the same thing. What you are doing is perfectly grammatical Ruby code -- in a sufficiently new Ruby. In older Rubies, you will need to use the old reliable hash-rocket syntax:

```
{ "foo".to_sym => 1, "bar" => 2 }
```

Now that you actually have a string, you can do normal interpolation:

```
{ "f#{'o' * 2}".to_sym => 1, "bar" => 2 }
```

In your case, you *could* write

```
{ "#{custom_key}".to_sym => 1 }
```

*However,* all of this is completely unnecessary, since you can just write simply this, in *any* Ruby:

```
{ custom_key.to_sym => 1 }
```

Even better, since you're just turning everything into JSON immediately after, you don't even need symbolised keys; so these two expressions will have identical results:

```
{ custom_key.to_sym => 1 }.to_json
{ custom_key => 1 }.to_json
```

(Also note that what you state as examples of JSON -- both input and output -- are, in fact, *not JSON*, nor would `.to_json` output such. In JSON, as opposed to plain JavaScript object literal, keys *must* be double-quoted, and that is how `to_json` would produce it. Your input is a Ruby valid Ruby hash, though.)